# How to set alert on prometheus itself like if prometheus is down we get an alert

Tags: prometheus

how can we monitor prometheus  itself, like if prometheus is down for that we want an alert in our slack channel.
we have tried this but not getting any desire output.

route:
receiver: "slack"
group_by:

- severity
- alertname
  routes:
- receiver: "cloudwatch"
  match:
  alertname: DeadMansSwitch
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 1m
  repeat_interval: 1m
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 1m
  repeat_interval: 48h
  receivers:
- name: "cloudwatch"
  webhook_configs:

  - url: "http://alertmanager-cloudwatch-webhook/webhook"
- name: "slack"

Comment: DeadManSwitch only works when your alerting system support heatbeats.
So your question is more related to CloudWatch rather than prometheus.
Googling it yields interesting results. You'd better try that out first and then reopen a question if you are blocked. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: no its not related with cloud watch